# Twilio webhook backup solutions

Tags: twilio, webhooks, failover

I want to implement a Twilio webhook to receive sms responses for my initial sms message. However, instead of implementing the secondary "failover" webhook URL, is there a way to call a Twilio REST service to find out which webhook callback from Twilio to my service failed so my application can retrieve the failed message from the failed webhook call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I definitely recommend implementing a fallback webhook so that you can at least record failures and know whether to call this other service.

However, you can call the [Twilio Monitor API to find out about Alerts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/monitor/alerts). This is a service that will give you information on all webhooks and REST API calls that your application has made that failed or produced a warning of some sort.

Let me know if that helps at all.